# Success Channel not picking the correct delegating factory

Tags: spring-integration

My success channel is taking a delegatingSessionFactory that contains a sessionFactoryLocator, and then based on the threadKey it should select the correct connection and send the file to that FTP server.

First when I run the application I do not have any integration flow running, I fill a form specifying the FTP server and location of the server where it will pull a file manipulate it and then sends back the output to the server and at the same time the success channel will send the original file as well to that server for archiving.

Based on my coding, the success channel is not picking the correct session and thus sending it to the correct archiving destination, it is only sending it to the default ftp session that is returning from the session locator.

So I want for example I insert FTP A then the success channel will send to FTP A archive folder, then if I enter another FTP B then the success channel will send to FTP B archive folder.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@ComponentScan
public class FTPIntegration {

public static final String TIMEZONE_UTC = "UTC";
public static final String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS";
public static final String TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX = ".part";
public static final int POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY = 5000;
public static final int MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL = 100;

private DataSource dataSource;

private static final Logger LOG1 = Logger.getLogger(FTPIntegration.class);
@Autowired
private CSVToCSVNoQ csvToCSVNoQ;

public FTPIntegration() {
}

@Autowired
BranchRepository branchRepository;

Map<Object, SessionFactory<FTPFile>> factories = new HashMap<>();
DefaultSessionFactoryLocator<FTPFile> defaultSessionFactoryLocator = new DefaultSessionFactoryLocator<FTPFile>(factories);

@Bean
public Branch myBranch() {
    return new Branch();
}

/**
 * The default poller with 5s, 100 messages , will poll the FTP folder location
 *
 * @return default poller.
 */
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    return Pollers
            .fixedDelay(POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY)
            .maxMessagesPerPoll(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
            .transactional()
            .get();
}

/**
 * The direct channel for the flow.
 *
 * @return MessageChannel
 */
@Bean
public MessageChannel stockIntermediateChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

/**
 * Get the files from a remote directory. Add a timestamp to the filename
 * and write them to a local temporary folder.
 *
 * @return IntegrationFlow
 */

/**
 * Method that creates a flow to read from FTP server the csv file
 * and transform it to a local folder with the name branch.
 *
 * @return IntegrationFlow
 */
public IntegrationFlow fileInboundFlowFromFTPServer(Branch myBranch) throws IOException {

    final FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec sourceSpecFtp = Ftp.inboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch))
            .preserveTimestamp(true)
            //.patternFilter("*.csv")
            .maxFetchSize(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
            .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath())
            .regexFilter("FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv")
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .localDirectory(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
            .temporaryFileSuffix(TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX);


           /* .localFilenameExpression(new FunctionExpression<String>(s -> {
                final int fileTypeSepPos = s.lastIndexOf('.');
                return DateTimeFormatter
                        .ofPattern(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES)
                        .withZone(ZoneId.of(TIMEZONE_UTC))
                        .format(Instant.now())
                        + "_"
                        + s.substring(0,fileTypeSepPos)
                        + s.substring(fileTypeSepPos);
            }));*/

    // Poller definition
    final Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> stockInboundPoller = endpointConfigurer -> endpointConfigurer
            .id("stockInboundPoller")
            .autoStartup(true)
            .poller(poller());

    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(sourceSpecFtp, stockInboundPoller)

            .transform(File.class, p -> {
                // log step
                LOG1.info("flow=stockInboundFlowFromAFT, message=incoming file: " + p);
                return p;
            })
            .handle(m -> {
                try {/* Invoking a method through the integration flow that reads a csv file and transform it to a new format that should be sent to FTP */
                    this.csvToCSVNoQ.writeCSVfinal("test", myBranch.getBranchCode() + "/final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv", myBranch.getBranchCode() + "/FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv");
                    LOG1.info("Writing final file .csv " + m);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
            .get();

    return flow;
}

/**
 * Creating the outbound adaptor to send files from local to FTP server
 *@return integration flow from local to FTP server
 */

public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow(Branch myBranch) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
                    .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                            .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv"))
                            .addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(dataSource), "foo"))),//FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))
            .enrichHeaders(h ->h.headerExpression("file_originalFile", "new java.io.File('"+ myBranch.getBranchCode() +"/FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv')",true))
            .transform(p -> {
                LOG1.info("Sending file " + p + " to FTP branch " + myBranch.getBranchCode());
                return p;
            })

            .log()
            .transform(m -> {
                        this.defaultSessionFactoryLocator.addSessionFactory(myBranch.getBranchCode(),createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch));
                        LOG1.info("Adding factory to delegation");
                        return m;
            })
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)

                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                    .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()), e -> e.advice(expressionAdvice()))

            .get();
}

/**
* Creating the advice for routing the payload of the outbound message on different expressions (success, failure)
* @return Advice
*/

@Bean
public Advice expressionAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload.delete() + ' was successful'");
    //advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("inputMessage.headers['file_originalFile'].renameTo(new java.io.File(payload.absolutePath + '.success.to.send'))");
    //advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}

/**
 * Creating FTP connection based on the branch ftp data entered.
 * @return ftpSessionFactory
 */

public DefaultFtpSessionFactory createNewFtpSessionFactory(Branch branch) {
    final DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost(branch.getHost());
    factory.setUsername(branch.getUsern());
    factory.setPort(branch.getFtpPort());
    factory.setPassword(branch.getPassword());
    return factory;
}

/**
 * Creating a default FTP connection.
 * @return ftpSessionFactory
 */
@Bean
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> createNewFtpSessionFactory() {
    final DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost("xxxxxxx");
    factory.setUsername("xxxxx");
    factory.setPort(21);
    factory.setPassword("xxxxxx");
    return factory;
}

/**
 * Creating a metadata store to be used across the application flows to prevent reprocessing the file if it is already processed.
 * This will save the new file in a metadata table in the DB with the state of the report, so when a new copy comes with different date it will be processed only.
 * @return metadataStore
 * */
@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
}

/*
* Success channel that will handle the AdviceMessage from the outbound adapter and sends the inputMessage file_originalFile to FTP destination folder specified.
*
* */

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow success(){
    return f -> f.transform("inputMessage.headers['file_originalFile']")
            .transform(e -> {
                //getting the Branch code from the Input message and calling the correct factory based on it
                delegatingSessionFactoryAuto().setThreadKey(e.toString().substring(0,3));
                return e;
            })
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(delegatingSessionFactoryAuto(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .remoteDirectory("/ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/History/").get());
}

@Bean
public DelegatingSessionFactory<FTPFile> delegatingSessionFactoryAuto(){

    SessionFactoryLocator<FTPFile> sff = createNewFtpSessionFactoryAndAddItToTheLocator();
    return new DelegatingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sff);
}

@Bean
public SessionFactoryLocator<FTPFile> createNewFtpSessionFactoryAndAddItToTheLocator(){

    this.defaultSessionFactoryLocator.addSessionFactory("BEY",createNewFtpSessionFactory());
    return this.defaultSessionFactoryLocator;
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like there is no a delegate associated with the `"CAI"` key. Also that `h.get(String.valueOf("inputMessage.headers['file_originalFile']",1,3)` is not clear for me. The is no going to be any SpEL evaluation at that `setThreadKey()` point.

Comment: I presume `localToFtpFlow` is a dynamically created flow - I don't see any logic to add your newly created `SessionFactory` to the locator.

Comment: Well I'm adding the key in the `sessionFactoryLocator()` and passing it in the `delegationSessionFactory()` but not sure I'm locating it correctly in the `success()`, you can ignore `h.get(...)` as I have commented it in the code, how can I do the SpEL evaluation in the `setThreadKey()`?..thanks@Artem Bilan

Comment: You are correct Gary it is dynamically created flow, I'm adding it to the locator in method `SessionFactoryLocator` so I assume that in the success channel when it hits `delegatingSessionFactory()` it will pull the branches from the DB using the `sessionFactoryLocator` and then `setThreadkey` will select the one I need to outbound to, not sure I'm correctly using it but this is what I could understand. Now from your reply I can understand that there should be a logic in the `localToFtpFlow` to add to the locator I guess I'm already doing this in the `sessionFactoryLocator` method @Gary Russell

Comment: If you create new session factories dynamically, each time you create a new session factory, you need to call `addSessionFactory` on the `DefaultSessionFactoryLocator`. If you are creating them during initialization (for loop in session factory locator bean) then you don't need to create them again.

Comment: How can I add it in the flow when I'm creating the session factories in method `localToFtpFlow`, the factory is being created in `outboundAdapter`, then I need to have it in the `delegatingSessionFactory()` for the success channel to pick the correct one and thus send it to the correct FTP server, thanks @Gary Russell

Comment: You are calling `createNewFtpSessionFactory` in two places. One when you are initializing the locator (in a loop). And one in the dynamic flow. You need a new method, something like `createNewFtpSessionFactoryAndAddItToTheLocator()` in the dynamic flow.

Comment: I have updated my code where I added this new function and what I think should work but in the success channel it is not picking FTP with key "BEY" although I'm adding this FTP dynamically as the first flow, maybe I'm missing something in the success channel to pick the correct session factory. @Gary Russel

Comment: You didn't do what I said; you now seem to be creating a new locator each time now. You simply need to create an initial locator and then, whenever you create a new factory for a new key, simply call `addSessionFactory()` on the locator bean.

Comment: Was able to get it solved and I have updated the code above to show the correct way to do it, thanks Gary for the guidance @Gary Russel